# Sent checked html table view back to client when invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

When my Model.State is NOT valid I want to return the view WITH the checked checkboxes.

How would you change my code? Is it possible at all with my approach?

**VIEW**

```
       @model ListTest.Models.PeopleListViewModel


    @{
        var hasMoreThanOnePerson = @Model.People.Count > 1;   
    }

    @Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home")
    {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model.People)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (hasMoreThanOnePerson)
             {
               <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedIds" value="@item.PersonId" />
                </td>
              }
              else
              {
                 @Html.Hidden("SelectedIds", item.PersonId)
              }

                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="@item.Name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public class PeopleListViewModel
    {
        public PeopleListViewModel()
        {
            SelectedIds = new int[] { };
        }

        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Minimum one person must be selected!")]
        public int[] SelectedIds { get; set; }

        public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var people = new List<Person> {
        new Person { Name = "Horst", PersonId = 10 }, 
        new Person { Name = "Michael", PersonId = 20} 
    };

    return View(new PeopleListViewModel { People = people });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PeopleListViewModel viewModel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 

    }

    viewModel.People = new List<Person> { new Person { Name = "Horst", PersonId = 10 }, new Person { Name = "bernarnd", PersonId = 20 } };

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if the user checked some, you want the same ones to be checked when you return the view, or that you want all checkboxes to be checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to change

Firstly, change your `People` model to include an `IsSelected` property, we want to do away with your `SelectedIds` method

Secondly, in order to post the data from the client, we need to rewrite your `foreach` to be a `for` so the fields are indexed correctly, we'll also add some extra `HiddenFor`s for the properties that you want to keep (because we're no longer re-populating your model when validation fails), your table will be:

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].PersonID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].Name)
            @if (hasMoreThanOnePerson)
            {
               <td>
                   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected)
               </td>
           }
           else
           {
               @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected)
           }

           <td>
              <input type="text" value="@Model.People[i].Name" />
           </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Finally, we don't reassign your `People` list in your action method if validation fails just return the model that was passed in. If you want to get the selected people, use the code I've added below. Also, because we don't have the `SelectedIds` anymore we can perform our own validation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PeopleListViewModel viewModel)
{
    List<People> selected = viewModel.People
        .Where(p => p.IsSelected)
        .ToList();

    if (selected.Any())
    { 
       //it's valid
      List<int> selectedIds = selected
          .Select(s => s.PersonID)
          .ToList();
    }

    return View("Index", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Fine that worked. When nothing is selected in the action would you do ModelState.AddError(string.empty, "you must choose a person!"); for the global validation summary or is there something better?

Comment: @Elisa I would probably do that to be honest, it's perfectly suited for this scenario.

Comment: Maybe you know :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099508/set-a-hardcoded-value-in-a-hiddenfor-within-a-for-loop