# Set a hardcoded value in a HiddenFor within a for-loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When there is only one person to select I still need to assign the hardcoded value 'TRUE' to the People[i].IsSelected property to satisfy my validation.

How can I do that?

```
@if (hasMoreThanOnePerson)
{
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected)
    </td>
}
else
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected, true) // Set TRUE always to hidden field within for loop with indexer
}
```

Comment: You using a strongly typed helper. Do not attempt to override the value of the property. Instead set the value of the property in your model - `model.IsSelected = true` before you pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htmlAttributes` to set `value` property of Hidden Field using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703468%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703622%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected, new {Value="true"})
```

It will output html like:

```
<input id="YourModel.People[0].IsSelected" 
       name="YourModel.People[0].IsSelected" 
       type="hidden" 
       value="true">
```

Comment: Such a trick I searched for! Thanks! Should it not be Value = true without quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the value to `true` inside the `else` block?

```
@if (hasMoreThanOnePerson)
{
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected)
    </td>
}
else
{
    @{ Model.People[i].IsSelected = true; }
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.People[i].IsSelected) // Set TRUE always to hidden field within for loop with indexer
}
```